# Indigo Igloo install on non-pae

Tags: ubuntu-precise, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have MB that has non pae cpu. I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 but it isnt possible. 12.04 works  but it is not supported by Indigo igloo. I tried forcepae and similiar things to install 14.04 but it wont start.

Can I install ROS Indigo Igloo on 12.04?

THank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212913/indigo-igloo-install-on-non-pae/) by [Tajcci](https://answers.ros.org/users/22599/tajcci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try a *from source* installation (ie: compile everything yourself), but it is a rather tedious process and more complicated.

See [wiki/indigo/Installation/Source](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source).

As Indigo is not supposed to run on Ubuntu Precise (see [REP-0003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#indigo-igloo-may-2014)), you could run into dependency issues. Those you will have to solve. Note that some dependencies might not be installable and / or compilable under Precise.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0